# Picard iteration and Taylor series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to derive the Taylor series for $\cos(t)$ by applying the Picard method to the first-order system corresponding to the second-order initial value problem

$x" = −x; x(0) = 1, x'(0) = 0$

For the above, I was thinking of converting the 2nd order DE to a first order, get a matrix which looks like:

$A = (0 0, 0 -1)^T$, but unsure on the Picard iteration here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We are given the system:

$\tag 1 x'' = −x; x(0) = 1, x'(0) = 0.$

To linearize $(1)$, we let $x_1 = x$ and $x_2 = x'$, yielding:

$\tag 2 x'_1 = x' = x_2 ~~~ \text{and} ~~ x'_2 = x'' = -x_1.$

This gives us the matrix: $A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}.$

Solving for the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$, yields:

$\lambda_1 = -i, v_1 = (i, 1)$ and $\lambda_2 = i, v_2 = (-i, 1).$

Using the eigenvalues, eigenvectors and initial conditions, we arrive at:

$$\tag 3 x_1(t) = - \cos  t ~~~~ \text{and} ~~~~ x_2(t) = \sin t.$$

You should verify that this satisfies the system in $(2)$ and derive it!

**Note**: Variations of solutions with varying signs are okay as long as they satisfy the linearized system (so, we can have $\cos t$ and $- \sin t$) as solutions too, but the Picard iteration will change accordingly.

We will want to compare the Taylor series for the solution above, so that would be:

$$\tag 4 \sin t = t- \frac{t^3}{6} + \frac{t^5}{120} + O(t^7) \\
\cos t = 1 - \frac{t^2}{2} + \frac{t^4}{24} - \frac{t^6}{720} + O(t^7)$$

Now, we want to form the Picard iterates on the linearized, first order system.

The Picard-Lindelof Iteration is given by:

$$\tag 5 \displaystyle x_0(t) = x_0, ~~x_{n+1}(t) = x_0 + \int^t_{t_0} f(s, x_n(s))ds$$

Of course, we are going to do this using both $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$ as called for by the linearization that we did earlier (two solutions to consider).

The setup uses $x(0) = (x_1(0),x_2(0))^T = (-1, 0)^T$ and then does the Picard iterates using $(5)$, so we have:

$X_{0}=  \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$ and $A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$, so

**First Iteration:**

$\displaystyle \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\0 \\ \end{bmatrix} + \int^{t}_{0} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\0 \\ \end{bmatrix} ds = \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ t \\ \end{bmatrix}$

**Second Iteration:**

$\displaystyle \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\0 \\ \end{bmatrix} + \int^{t}_{0} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ s \\ \end{bmatrix} ds = \begin{bmatrix} -1 + \frac{t^2}{2} \\ t \end{bmatrix}$

**Third Iteration:**

$\displaystyle \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\0 \\ \end{bmatrix} + \int^{t}_{0} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} -1 +\frac{s^2}{2} \\ s \end{bmatrix} ds = \begin{bmatrix} -1 +\frac{t^2}{2} \\ t -\frac{t^3}{6} \end{bmatrix}$

**Fourth Iteration:**

$\displaystyle \begin{bmatrix} -1 \\0 \\ \end{bmatrix} + \int^{t}_{0} \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}  -1 + \frac{s^2}{2} \\ s -\frac{s^3}{6} \end{bmatrix} ds = \begin{bmatrix} -1 +\frac{t^2}{2} - \frac{t^4}{24} \\ t - \frac{t^3}{6} \end{bmatrix}$

Notice what this is converging to? Compare these to the series expansions we wrote above in $(4)$. The top term in your $- \cos t$ the bottom is $\sin t$, as expected.

Although we see that this is converging to the $x_1(t) = -\cos t$ and $x_2(t) = \sin t$ results, you should really prove this using an inductive argument.

For an inductive argument, you would write the vector we are deriving as a function of $n$ and then use induction that it is true and gives the $x_1(t)$ and $x_2(t)$.

Comment: @BuddyHolly: I updated the result to use the $x_1(t) = -\cos t$ and $x_2(t) = \sin t$, so you can see that that is okay and works too. Of course, when you are comparing the $- \cos t$ terms, make sure to note the alternating sign.

Comment: @BuddyHolly: see my bolded note regarding the solutions and also the addition at the end for induction - which I doubt you have to do (I like being complete). Hopefully, it makes sense to you. It would be good for you to repeat this entire iteration using your variant of solutions and make sure that you end up with the Picard iterates that give the righ series expansion.  Regards

Comment: @Amzoti, I don't understand the inductive argument hint you have. Could you please fill in the details? thx

Comment: @BuddyHolly: You are trying to show that the Picard terms converge to sin and cosine series and there are only a few terms shown. You would write out a general formula using $n$ for the n-th term and then use the induction process to show that it converges to those trig functions. Regards